# Как сделать так чтобы в editText, можно было вводить неограниченное количество символов (Android)

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так чтобы в `EditText`,  можно было вводить неограниченное количество символов.  При этом  на экране показывалась бы всегда определённое значение,  к примеру (15).   И при этом чтобы всё это можно было скролить   в сторону и смотреть остальные значения .

Comment: Для хранения неограниченного количества символов нужен неограниченный объем устройства хранения. Вы видели телефон с бесконечным объёмом памяти?

Comment: "И при этом чтобы всё это можно было скролить в сторону и смотреть остальные значения" - `android:singleLine="true"`